# What to include in Require.js define() with Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have this file in /utils/routerExtend.js:

```
(function() {
  _.extend(Backbone.Router.prototype, Backbone.Events, {
    before: function() {},
    after: function() {},
    route: function(route, name, callback) {
      Backbone.history || (Backbone.history = new Backbone.History);
      if (!_.isRegExp(route)) route = this._routeToRegExp(route);
      if (!callback) callback = this[name];
      Backbone.history.route(route, _.bind(function(fragment) {
        var that = this;
        var args = this._extractParameters(route, fragment);
        if (_(this.before).isFunction()) {
          this.before.apply(this, args);
        }
        if (callback) callback.apply(that, args);
        if (_(this.after).isFunction()) {
          this.after.apply(this, args);
        }
      }, this));
    }
  });
}).call(this);
```

Now, I'm new to Require (in fact, never used it, just getting my head around it's use/advantages for my app), do I have to include this along with Backbone every time I do this:

`define(["backbone", "/utils/routerExtend.js"], function(Backbone, ???) {`

Is the above correct?

And also, how do I make my routerExtend.js an actual module? Struggling to get started on this unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to include this in every file which is using index.html.

```
define(["backbone", "/utils/routerExtend.js"], function(Backbone, ???) {
```

??? will be whatever var you are using in that file for /utils/routerExtend.js
Like this maybe:

```
define(["backbone", "/utils/routerExtend.js"], function(Backbone, RouterExtend) {
```

what the above line will do is that it will load /utils/routerExtend.js script in variable RouterExtend and then you can use RouterExtend var anywhere in that file wherever you want to use /utils/routerExtend.js.

Answer (score 0):

You could set deps in your config. So something like this:

```
var require = {
  paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/jquery',
    underscore: 'lib/underscore',
    backbone: 'lib/backbone'
  },
  shim: {
    backbone: {
      deps: ['jquery', 'underscore']
      exports: 'Backbone',
      init: function($, _){
        var Backbone = this.Backbone;
        _.extend(Backbone.Router.prototype, Backbone.Events, {
          // your setup code here
        })
        return Backbone;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

More details here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Another way will be create your own 'backbone model' in mybackbone.js:

```
define(["backbone"], function(Backbone) {
  _.extend(Backbone.Router.prototype, Backbone.Events, {
    // your setup code here
  });
  return Backbone
});
```

Then use mybackbone in your project instead of original one.

Comment: Will that work? It was pointed out that routerExtend depends on BB, not the other way around?

Comment: Sorry, my last answer won't work in your case. I change my answer to use "shim init" instead.